# Angular 4 Listen for setValue or patchValue instead of using valueChanges

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've added a floating point directive to fields in a reactive form that adds comma's to every 1000 and appends `.00` to field values specifically for readability within the UI, which works great.

- onBlur adds formatting
- onFocus removes formatting

When the form loads with existing values I wanted these values to be formatted so I added this to my floating point directive so values were formated once as the form fields are filled using `setValue` or `patchValue`, which worked great.

**Snippet from Floating Point Directive**

```
public ngOnInit() {
  this.formatFloat();
}

private formatFloat() {
  const handle = this.ngControl.valueChanges
    .subscribe((value: string) => {
      const float = this.getFloat();
      if (float) {
        this.element.value = this.format(value);
      }
      handle.unsubscribe();
    });
}
```

> ** Added the full directive below, but this is only part that really matters.

But if you are dynamically adding form fields to a FormArray as you fill out an empty form this won't have triggered the one time formatting so the first digit you type into the field adds the formatting. For example, open up an empty form, click a button to add a dynamic field, type `1` into the field triggers the one time `valueChange` and the input now has `1.00` and the user will keep on typing `1.001244` instead of `11244`.

I know `patchValue` and `setValue` are directly linked to `valueChanges` through the `emitEvent` [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html), but  is there a way to listen for `setValue` or `patchValue` changes instead of listening for `valueChanges`?  Or is there another way I can get this to work, but still have the existing functionality since even just listening to `setValue` and `patchValue` would mean the one time format subscription would still be alive.

**Floating Point Directive**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { FormGroup, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[cfFloat]',
  providers: [DecimalPipe] // TODO: why do I need this?
})
export class FloatDirective implements OnInit {
  public element: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe,
    private ngControl: NgControl
  ) {
    this.element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  @HostListener('blur', ['$event'])
  onBlur(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const float = this.getFloat();
    if (float) {
      this.element.value = this.format(float);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('focus', ['$event'])
  onFocus(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const float = this.getFloat();
    if (float) {
      this.element.value = this.replace(float);
    }
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.formatFloat();
  }

  private formatFloat() {
    const handle = this.ngControl.valueChanges
      .subscribe((value: string) => {
        const float = this.getFloat();
        if (float) {
          this.element.value = this.format(value);
        }
        handle.unsubscribe();
      });
  }

  private getFloat(): string {
    const value = this.element.value;
    const float = this.replace(value);
    // Only perform an action when a floating point value exists and there are
    // no errors, otherwise leave the erroneous value to be fixed manually by
    // ignoring an action
    if (value && float && this.checkIsValid()) {
      return float;
    }
  }

  private checkIsValid(): boolean {
    return !this.ngControl.control.errors;
  }

  private replace(value: string): string {
    return value.replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, '');
  }

  private format(value: string) {
    return this.decimalPipe.transform(value, '1.2-2');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured this out.  Not a horrible fix, but seems like it could be more elegant maybe... always up for suggestions.

```
private onInitFormatHandler: Subscription; // <-- ADDED HANDLER AS MEMBER VARIABLE INSTEAD

@HostListener('focus', ['$event'])
onFocus(event: KeyboardEvent) {

  // Remove initial formatting subscription since no patch of the value has
  // occurred, and is no longer likely to occur if the user is actively
  // applying focus
  // ---
  // NOTE: Not unsubscribing causes formatting to occur on dynamically added
  // fields on the first change of the input value prior to blur
  if (!this.onInitFormatHandler.closed) { // <-- ADDED CHECK AND EXTRA UNSUBSCRIPTION
    this.onInitFormatHandler.unsubscribe();
  }

  const float = this.getFloat();
  if (float) {
    this.element.value = this.replace(float);
  }
}

public ngOnInit() {
  this.formatFloat();
}

/**
 * Format the input value only once after the initial form response has
 * patched the model.
 * ---
 * NOTE: Format handler is stored and unsubscribed either on valueChange, or
 * if focus is applied to the field, whichever occurs first.
 */
private formatFloat() {
  this.onInitFormatHandler = this.ngControl.valueChanges // <-- UPDATED HANDLER TO BE MEMBER VARIABLE
    .subscribe((value: string) => {
      const float = this.getFloat();
      if (float) {
        this.element.value = this.format(value);
      }
      this.onInitFormatHandler.unsubscribe(); // <-- UPDATED HANDLER TO BE MEMBER VARIABLE
    });
}
```